# Android: clearing the backstack is causing java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: android, fragment-backstack

The code is

```
context.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

In order to avoid the exception (I have no idea what is causing it), I added

```
if (!context.getSupportFragmentManager().isStateSaved())
```

before the previous line of code but then, on rare occasions, the backstack is messed up causing back to go to the previous fragment while the backstack was suppose to be empty.

I just want to clear the backstack completely without exceptions.

Comment: FragmentManager is not a field of context (Probably you think it because of activity). Try FragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(0, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)

Comment: Actually context is a parameter to the function (in a singleton) that replaces fragments: MainActivity context. If I try your way, I get a message saying non static method cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: you need a fragment manger instance to call that method, just replace your code like this context.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(0, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)

Comment: The only difference I see between your code and mine is 0 instead of null. This is the change you're talking about? My code works, at some unknown occasion on a user's device, it fails. I don't even know how to reproduce.

Comment: Any news on how to solve this?